# Use XML Schema to extend an element rather than a complexType

Tags: xml, xsd

Suppose I have some schema:

```
<xsd:schema ...>
    <xsd:element name="foo">
         <xsd:complexType>
             <xsd:sequence>
                 <xsd:element name="fooElement" type="xs:string" />
             </xsd:sequence>
         </xsd:complexType>
    </xsd:element>
</xsd:schema>
```

This defines some element `foo` which has inside it some element `fooElement` with type string.  I'd like to now extend element `foo` to also have an element `barElement` and call this extension `bar`.

To complicate things, let's also suppose that someone else has defined `foo` and the schema cannot be changed.  While the example here is trivial, let's also assume that the contents of `foo` might be more complicated, and that defining a new schema isn't quite as simple as copying the element `fooElement`.

Effectively, I'd like to define a new schema:

```
<xsd:schema xmlns:fns="otherschema" ...>
    <xsd:import namespace="otherschema" />
    <xsd:element name="bar">
         <xsd:complexContent>
             <xsd:extension base="fns:foo">
                 <xsd:sequence>
                     <xsd:element name="barElement" type="xs:string" />
                 </xsd:sequence>
             </xsd:extension>
         </xsd:complexContent>
    </xsd:element>
</xsd:schema>
```

Unfortunately `<xsd:extension>`'s `base` attribute only accepts XSD type arguments, not elements.  How do I extend an element? (can I extend an element?)

Comment: Great question, I'd like to do the exact same thing — and I'm incredulous that it seems impossible. Crazy!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would create a new type that mimics foo element and then extend from it.  While it's not the best solution, you do get the same result as if you were able to extend the element directly.

```
  <xs:complexType name="fooType">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="fooElement" type="xs:string" />
    </xs:sequence>
   </xs:complexType>

   <xs:complexType name="barType">
    <xs:complexContent mixed="false">
      <xs:extension base="fooType">
        <xs:sequence>
          <xs:element name="barElement" type="xs:string" />
        </xs:sequence>
      </xs:extension>
    </xs:complexContent>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:element name="bar" type="barType" />
```

Comment: Wouldn't this force me to encapsulate the element every time I called it? <element name="bar" type="fooType"> would result in syntax like <bar><foo /></bar> rather than simply <bar /> ... which is undesirable.

Comment: No, the result is I think what you were asking for: <bar><fooElement/><barElement/></bar>

Comment: That sounds like a very verbose solution if the `foo` element has any `key` or `keyref` things in it, as they will have to be repeated for the `bar` element, as far as I can see :-(